How can I determine direction of flipped UVs?
I'm working with a mesh created for a rendering engine that has no problem with UVs folded upon themselves, when using a normal map. The destination engine certainly does however, so it's important that I unflip these UVs.
Through my own research, I've discovered that Blender will display the mesh as it would appear in the other engine, as far as flipped UVs go, by leaving the normal map's color space set to sRBG rather than non-color. Yes, I realize you're supposed to set it to non-color, and by doing so the mesh looks great, but my goal isn't to just use it in Blender.
So, the fix, in theory, is pretty straightforward—flip the UV face in the proper direction in relation to the tile it exists in, and then change its material with textures that are flipped in the same direction. This way, the UVs are still mapped to the exact same area of the texture after they're no longer flipped. Of course, the appropriate channel of the normal map is inverted (red for horizontal flipping, green for vertical).
Unfortunately, other than looking at the UVs to see how they're folded, I have no way to determine direction. Even worse, the way Blender identifies flipped UVs is a bit too simplistic. Namely comparing the sign of the area of the UV triangle and its corresponding mesh triangle. Now this will detect flipped UVs, but only if they're flipped in one direction. This is because if you flip a UV in both directions, it's effectively just rotated 180 degrees, rather than inverted.
So, what I need to do is go over every UV triangle and determine its direction relative to its corresponding mesh triangle. This way, I should be able to figure out which way it needs to be flipped and make the appropriate changes.
Only problem is that I'm a bit out of my league on the necessary math. I'm thinking comparing the direction of each UV triangle edge to its corresponding mesh edge, should give me an idea?
upon feedback, I've replaced the original blender file with one of the actual project meshes, and to start out, here's the normal map:

and here's a rundown of what the issue is:

This is the default mesh, with its normal map applied, set to the color space of sRGB, and material settings tweaked to eliminate all shine/reflection. Note the splitting and abrupt changes in shading. This is an indication of flipped UVs

With Magic UV enabled, I can select flipped UVs, which correlates perfectly with the previous screenshot. The reason everything looks selected on the left is because the UV mapping which is often folded in upon itself in order to conserve space.

Unfortunately, fixing this isn't quite as simple as flipping these UV faces in place, as these faces all must retain their position in relation to the texture in order for the mesh to display the intended detail. The solution is in 3 parts.

separate the flipped UV faces from a particular UV island into a separate mesh

flip these faces in the correct direction in relation to the UV tile it's on. So if the original flipped UV faces are on the left side of the tile, and you flip them horizontally, they should end up on the right side.

create a new set of textures by horizontally flipping the originals - being sure to invert the red channel of the Normal map to make said map work as intended. Do the equivalent for a third set of textures, this time vertically flipping them.

apply the horizontally flipped textures to the new mesh.

repeat until everything is flipped.



After applying this method to the outer ring, you can tell the splitting is gone, and the shading is now consistent. This is the goal, so lets move onto the inner ring.

And now we have a problem - yes, it's true that the seams are gone, but now we're left with a smooth gradient from one end to the other.


Could you provide a Blender file with "well defined UVs" for a representative object and "flipped UVs" for a duplicate of this same object (along U, along V, and along both U and V) ? I think a GeometryNodes modifier could do what you are looking for. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share this minimal setup.

Honestly, I don't understand the question. Illustrating your question with some sketches, or screenshots of the .blend and arrows pointing to what exactly and how it is flipped could be a good way of communicating the problem further. Also consider using a simpler mesh with fewer faces as an example so it's easier to localize the changes and reason about the logic behind the changes...

pls add the images + text to your question, not as external link in the comments...

You're right. I've already clearly described by problem and stated my question so that anyone capable of providing an answer can do so.

Could you confirm that in the provided Blender file, the "Sphere" object has "well defined UVs", while the "Sphere.001" object is the pathological one ?

yes, Sphere is default UVs while Sphere.001 is the one with flipped UVs done by mirroring on the X, on the Y and both. Note how only the UVs flipped in one direction show up as flipped when using Magic UV. I'm not sure if .blend files include textures but if not, just use the default color (RGB: 127,127,255) instead of the image texture to see the effect flipped UVs has on the normals

Could you just add to your question as an image the texture file (test_N.dds) ? Because if I put (0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0) as Color in the Normal Map node, both spheres are rendered the same...

I updated the question to include a normal map and an actual project file. If you want to keep it simple, feel free to use the normal map with the original spheres. Also, remember to set the color space to sRGB

Thanks. I am still working on this. Quite a challenge !

My trig/geometry knowledge sucks, but I imagine with a particular triangle's vertex coordinates and the UVW coordinates of the corresponding texture face, the winding order of each could be compared, and the result should give way to determine which ways the UV face is flipped

The mirrored normals is a unique data and either must be resolved at the renderer level or baked into a new normal map.
Duplicate and flip
A script to flip mirrored UVs along side with creating a second material and a second set of mirrored textures. This will not work if there are procedural UV transformations.

import typing
import bpy
import os


T = typing.TypeVar('T')
T2 = typing.TypeVar('T2')


def list_by_key(items: typing.Collection[T], key_func: typing.Callable[[T], T2]) -> typing.Dict[T2, typing.List[T]]:
    result: typing.Dict[T2, typing.List[T]] = {}
    for item in items:
        result.setdefault(key_func(item), []).append(item)
    return result


def select_objects(objects):

    import bpy

    object: bpy.types.Object
    for object in bpy.context.view_layer.objects:
        object.select_set(object in objects)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objects[0]

    return objects


def flip_image(image, flip_x_channel = False):

    import numpy

    pixels = numpy.empty(len(image.pixels), dtype = numpy.float32)
    image.pixels.foreach_get(pixels)

    x, y = image.size
    pixels = pixels.reshape((x, y, 4))

    pixels = numpy.fliplr(pixels)

    if flip_x_channel:
        pixels[:, :, 0] = 1 - pixels[:, :, 0]

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(image.name)
    new_name = name + '_flipped' + ext

    new_image = bpy.data.images.new(name = new_name, width = x, height = y, is_data = image.colorspace_settings.is_data)
    new_image.colorspace_settings.name = image.colorspace_settings.name
    new_image.pixels.foreach_set(pixels.flatten())

    return new_image


def flip_images(material):

    image_nodes = [node for node in material.node_tree.nodes if node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeTexImage' and node.image]

    unique_images = list_by_key(image_nodes, lambda x: x.image)

    normal_image_nodes = set()

    for link in material.node_tree.links:
        if link.to_node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeNormalMap' and link.from_node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeTexImage':
            normal_image_nodes.add(link.from_node)

    for image, nodes in unique_images.items():

        if not image.pixels:
            continue

        flipped_image = flip_image(image, flip_x_channel = not normal_image_nodes.isdisjoint(nodes))

        for node in nodes:
            node.image = flipped_image



def flip_mirrored_uvs_and_images(objects):

    import bpy
    import bmesh

    bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module='magic_uv')
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_uv_select_sync = False

    mesh_to_objects = list_by_key(objects, lambda x: x.data)

    mesh: bpy.types.Mesh
    for mesh, objects in mesh_to_objects.items():

        select_objects([objects[0]])


        # material and image
        flipped_material = mesh.materials[0].copy()
        flipped_material.name = mesh.materials[0].name + '_flipped'
        mesh.materials.append(flipped_material)
        material_index = len(mesh.materials) - 1

        flip_images(flipped_material)

        # uv and material_index
        init_mode = objects[0].mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)

        bpy.ops.mesh.reveal()

        b_mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

        for uv_layer in mesh.uv_layers:
            uv_layer.active = True

            bpy.ops.uv.reveal()

            bpy.ops.uv.muv_select_uv_select_flipped(selection_method='RESET', sync_mesh_selection=False)

            uv_layer = b_mesh.loops.layers.uv.verify()

            for face in b_mesh.faces:
                for loop in face.loops:
                    if loop[uv_layer].select:
                        face.material_index = material_index
                        loop[uv_layer].uv[0] = 1 - loop[uv_layer].uv[0]

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, loop_triangles=False, destructive=False)

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=init_mode, toggle=False)


flip_mirrored_uvs_and_images([bpy.context.object])


Baking
A script to separate the flipped UVs to later pack the UVs with preserving overlaps and bake the normals but that's no longer a trimsheet and repeats the mirrored normals.
There could be a better solution that preserves the trimsheet quality of the texture and does not use bpy.ops.uv.muv_clip_uv.


import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
T2 = typing.TypeVar('T2')


def list_by_key(items: typing.Collection[T], key_func: typing.Callable[[T], T2]) -> typing.Dict[T2, typing.List[T]]:
    result: typing.Dict[T2, typing.List[T]] = {}
    for item in items:
        result.setdefault(key_func(item), []).append(item)
    return result


def select_objects(objects):

    import bpy

    object: bpy.types.Object
    for object in bpy.context.view_layer.objects:
        object.select_set(object in objects)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objects[0]

    return objects


def magic_uv_clip_and_shift_flipped(objects):

    import bpy
    import bmesh

    bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module='magic_uv')

    mesh_to_objects = list_by_key(objects, lambda x: x.data)

    mesh: bpy.types.Mesh
    for mesh, objects in mesh_to_objects.items():

        select_objects([objects[0]])

        mesh.uv_layers[0].active_clone = True
        mesh.uv_layers[0].active = True
        bake_uv = mesh.uv_layers.new(name = '_new_uvs')
        bake_uv.active = True

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)

        bpy.ops.mesh.reveal()
        bpy.ops.uv.reveal()
        bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='SELECT')

        bpy.ops.uv.muv_clip_uv(clip_uv_range_max=(0.5, 0.5), clip_uv_range_min=(-0.5, -0.5))

        bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.ops.uv.muv_select_uv_select_flipped(selection_method='RESET', sync_mesh_selection=False)

        b_mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

        uv_layer = b_mesh.loops.layers.uv.verify()

        for face in b_mesh.faces:
            for loop in face.loops:
                if loop[uv_layer].select:
                    loop[uv_layer].uv[1] -= 2
                    loop[uv_layer].uv[0] *= -1

        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, loop_triangles=False, destructive=False)

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
        
        
import bpy

magic_uv_clip_and_shift_flipped([bpy.data.objects["Geo_Ship_Fed_Fc3_Saucer_Type1_2019"]])

bpy.types.MeshLoop.bitangent_sign is limited to triangles and quads RuntimeError: Error: Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting and has an issue with zero aria faces.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshLoop.html#bpy.types.MeshLoop.bitangent_sign
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
mesh = o.data

mesh.calc_tangents()


signs = [0.0] * len(mesh.loops)
mesh.loops.foreach_get('bitangent_sign', signs)


uv_layer = mesh.uv_layers.active

for index, sing in enumerate(signs):
    uv_layer.vertex_selection[index].value = sing == -1

mesh.free_tangents()
# [-1. -1. -1. ... -1. -1. -1.]


Thanks for your answer, but I fear as the bitangent and tangent are related, which are, in turn related to the V and U coordinates of the UV, this could result in false positive results if a face is horizontally and vertically flipped. I'm thinking of some method that is independent of the UVs - either a way to identify the direction of the fliip(s) or a way to get the appropriate direction and flip each face by trial and error until achieving that direction

There is no difference between an island that is flipped by U and V and one rotated by 180 degrees for 2D. tangent_sign or bitangent_sign is used for tangent space normal maps. bitangent = bitangent_sign * cross(normal, tangent)). You can preview tangent_sign values by using the Attribute node in Cycles. Normal maps should not be used with sRGB and it is not related to tangent sign. Also your test_N.dds was not packed into the blend.

Not clear what your end goal is. Post screenshots of how the result looks in your engine, the target engine and Blender. If the problem is with some of the engines respecting or not respecting the tangent sign — the islands you should care about is the flipped ones only by one axis. And then whether or not you can flip without changing the look depends on the symmetry and directionality of the texture.

Yes, but isn't the tangent affected by the U coord of the UV? agreed on the result of flipping horizontally and vertically but we're talking about a mesh originally made for an engine that doesn't care what direction UV faces are. In most other engines the UV generally has to match the orientation it was baked for?

Yes, I realize in Blender that Normal Maps should be set to non-color, but using sRGB is the only way I can replicate the effect as it appears in the target engine It's more noticeable in 3ds Max, but obviously that's getting off topic. Sorry, I didn't see the option for embedding textures, but you can replace it with a default map (RGB=127,127,255) and see the effect. I tried linking to an imgur album but got yelled at telling me I should put it and the descriptions in my question. And if I do that I'll probably get shamed for my question being too long.

Are you talking only about tangent space normal maps? Tangent sign is usually should not matter, should not be baked into normal maps and is handled at the tangent to world space transformations. If the tangent space normal map was baked for a specific UV map when it should be used with that UV map as it is baked for that specific set of UVs, tangents and normals. Editing the UVs and the texture without re-baking depends on the texture and the model. As a general solution it should be re-baked. The usual tiling normal map is a common case of normals baked for a plane that makes things easier.

I am making a lot of guessing. It would be better if you share imagery of the model you are trying to convert.

yeah, it's definitely tangent space, but unless the engine is specifically designed to support it, texture faces can't be folded back on themselves. If this was just a matter of floating islands that were flipped I could've easily done this manually. But the islands typically consist of a strip of faces pointing the correct direction, and then at least one connected strip folded back upon itself. Making visual detection nearly impossible. I"ll update the question with the project mesh and info/pics from the imgur gallery in a bit.

I wanted to keep things simple, because I thought it's just some 3d math I was ignorant about, but welcome to my hell lol

What is the target renderer that cannot handle such textures? The texture uses a manual compression by reusing parts of the trimsheet texture including the mirroring. Do you want to repack the trimsheet to get rid of the mirrored UVs? Or do you want to bake each island uniquely?

So I had to come up with a solution to deal with the fact that if these UVs are unflipped, they'll no longer match up to the original texture. So I figured if they were unflipped relative to the tile they exist in, I could separate them into a separate object, and give it a material with appropriately flipped textures. This also includes inverting the appropriate Normal map channel (red for horizontal flip, green for vertical) so that the unflipped UVs still cover the appropriate portion of the texture.

but it's not the textures that's a problem - Blender actually visually ignores flipped UVs in the default viewport renderer, provided the normal map's color space is set appropriately. But the target engine (Creation Engine 2.0) does not like flipped UVs, so to achieve a similar appearance, the color space is set to sRGB.

I cannot believe Creation Engine has issues with the flipped UVs. What is the format of the engine's normal maps? The compression specification and what each channel corresponds to relative to the OpenGL Y+ format that Blender uses.

most engines and renderers do when it comes to flipped UVs and normal maps - which is why everything from blender to Maya to 3ds Max has tools to select them. Considering tangent/bitangent are dependent on UVs and Normals, is it really a surprise that the texture that exists to modify normals is affected by flipped UV faces?

I guess one solution would be to separate the flipped UVs and appropriately invert the appropriate normal map channels on the areas those flipped faces appear, using trial and error but it would be far easier if I could determine the direction via python.

Do you use https://github.com/SesamePaste233/StarfieldMeshConverter ? I found a person with a similar issue and the problem was with the exporter and was resolved later in an update. I have an automated solution for re-baking the materials without flipped UVs but the set-up is experimental.

I do use it, but the fact I get the same result in 3ds Max, makes me doubt that the exporter is to blame. And the reason I bring up 3ds Max is that not only is it what Bethesda uses, but the fact that I converted the source of a tool created to convert the original format to a more common mesh format, into a .NET library for maxscript. For Blender I ported the necessary code from that tool to Python to import it. I figure either way it's best to resolve the flipped UVs.

On that note, I do have another approach in mind. If I can access or calculate the final face normals after being altered by the normal map and UVs, I can use a completely neutral normal map, and all the faces with UVs oriented correctly should have face normals equal to the mesh's face normals, while any faces with poorly oriented UVs would have a different result, which could theoretically be used to determine flip direction.

I don't believe the Creation Engine don't support flipped UVs. The technique exists for 3 decades and is prominent in games engines. Also I saw mentions that their assets do use mirrored UVs.

Well, after looking into it, the version I downloaded via Github shows the last release on January 29th (Release v0.15-h4), and the blender plugin's init.py is showing: "version": (0, 15, 4). But just to be sure, I just downloaded it again, removed the original addon, and installed the new one. Now, I can tell you that the one difference I've noticed is that the version that showed in Blender went from 0.16 to 0.15.4, so at the very least the author fixed the version number, but it seems odd that the fix you referred to wouldn't warrant a new version.

I should add that the example added to my question, where I unflipped the appropriate UVs on the outer and inner rings, that led to a great looking outer ring, and a weird gradient on the inner ring was exported, and the result was the same in game. Every piece of evidence I've encountered has led me to the conclusion that the UVs are to blame. And while I'm willing to accept there's a much simpler solution that I've overlooked, I've yet to see one

Join the exporter's Discord: https://discord.gg/4eKExKkKF7 Similar issues are discussed there. It is a Blender to the engine conversion issue.

but like I said, if the issue has been fixed, and I'm using the latest version, then its unrelated

The latest version on GitHub is this one https://github.com/SesamePaste233/StarfieldMeshConverter/raw/master/dist/tool_export_mesh/tool_export_mesh.zip and it is 16. Starfield does use mirrored UVs. The problem is in the exporting process not Blender. The only way you can have the mirrored normals look without having the mirrored UVs is to bake it onto a new not mirrored UV map.

Result is the same https://imgur.com/a/79GzGjX

By the way, you can most certainly flip UVs without baking a new normal map. The process goes like this: 1. separate the flipped UVs of a particular island into a new mesh. 2. flip said UVs by flipping the UV coords relative to the tile they reside in. 3. Create a new material 4. flip the original textures in the same way 5. When it comes to the normal map, invert the appropriate channel to the flip direction to compensate for flipping the entire texture. 6. apply these new textures to the new material. This way the formerly flipped UVs will match up to the same position they did originally,

Creating a new normal map by mirroring in this case is practically the same as baking the mirroring onto a new normal map. I tried to approach it without increasing amount of objects, materials and textures.

that's regrettably unavoidable- you can't flip asymmetrical sets of UVs and have them cover the exact same part of the texture. The only other option is to ceate an entirely new texture set with the lack of flipping in mind. Obviously something that would take far more than math to produce

well, not really, except, I would need to determine the flip direction so when I used the current UVs to generate a new texture set from the originals, designed for a UV layout without any flipping, I'd know how to lay it out.

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Progress Report
(NB: This answer is still under work, and it will most probably evolved with feedbacks).
Objectives

To find a diagnostic process identifying faces with flipped UV, discriminating flipped U, flipped V and flipped U&V cases.
To attach flipped textures to such faces after correction of UV map.

Approach
To simplify investigations, the outer ring of the hull is isolated as an object. To do so, in Edit Mode, the original object is firstly split in 96 parts using Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts. Then a face of the outer ring is selected, and the remaining faces are selected using Select > Select Linked > Linked with Delimit UVs setup. Eventually, the outer ring is isolated using Mesh > Separate > Selection. Remaining parts are moved in a collection.
In Shading Editor, a Generated UV Color Grid node is linked as Base Color to the Principled BSDF shader. The provided normal map is uploaded as "NormalMap.png" and it is input in an Image Texture node linked to a Normal Map node. It is to notice that the Color Space is set to sRGB, instead of Non-Color, to match the result achieved with "the other rendering engine".

Analysis

1. The top right figure of this picture shows that the UV map of the outer ring is divided in four parts using the same portion of the "UV Color Grid" picture. The U direction is in the "azimuthal" direction whereas the V direction is in the "radial" direction, pointing outward.
2. The left figure shows that the UV map of the outer ring is restricted to a rectangle, outside of the $[0,1]^2$ space. But thanks to the property Extension of the Image Texture nodes set to Repeat, it does not matter.
3. To illustrate how the original UV mapping is folded upon itself, four "symmetric" triangles are selected in the bottom right figure. These are drawn superimposed in the left view.
4. As a conclusion, the NE and SW quarters are rendered as expected with U clockwise, while the NW and SE quarters are showing UV flipped in U direction, U increasing counter-clockwise.

Identifying flipped UV faces
The objective of this section is to identify faces with flipped U or V direction (not U&V).


These pictures illustrate that a GeometryNodes modifier, detailed thereafter, can reproduce the same analysis as the Magic UV add-on. Flipped faces are rendered in red, regular faces in blue.
GeometryNodes graph

(NB: only the four leftmost nodes of the main graph are relevant for this section)
1. By default, the Blue material is set to all faces.
2. The Flipped Face group node is returning a boolean attribute True for faces with flipped U or V direction, without indication of which one.
3. For such faces, the material is changed to Red using a second Set Material node.

It is assumed that all faces are triangles. Let $M_0$, $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the three vertices of such a face.
1. The index of $M_0$ is recovered by a Capture Attribute node, set in Face domain, connected to a Corners of Face node. With default settings, it is returning the vertex with the smallest index.
2. Indices of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are recovered from $M_0$ with Offset Corner in Face nodes. (Side note: the bottom Offset Corner in Face node with Offset set to 0 is useless. It is nevertheless introduce to keep the symmetry of the process for the three vertices.)
3. For increasing offsets, the Offset Corner in Face node is providing vertices turning around the face in the direct direction defined by the face normal in XYZ space, labelled $\vec{n}$. Consequently, the cross product $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2} \times \overrightarrow{M_1M_0}$ is always pointing in the same direction as $\vec{n}$ in XYZ coordinate system.
4. The UV mapping of a face is flipped if vertices $M_0$, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are ordered in UV coordinate system in clockwise direction.
5. Let W be the third direction such that UVW defines a direct system. The cross product $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2} \times \overrightarrow{M_1M_0}$ computed in UV coordinate system is aligned with W direction. Consequently, the UV mapping of a face is flipped if the W coordinate of this cross product is negative.
6. The UVMap is stored in an attribute named "Float2". Its values are recovered at vertices $M_0$, $M_1$ and $M_2$ with Sample Index nodes set in Face Corner domain to be connected to Offset Corner in Face nodes.
7. It is to notice that vectors $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{M_1M_0}$ are Normalized before computing the Cross Product to reduce numerical errors and to make the Less Than 0 comparison less sensitive for highly stretched triangles.
8. Eventually, the "Flipped" criterion computation is triggered by a Capture Attribute node set in Face domain.

Identifying flipped condition
The objective of this section is to determine if U or V coordinate is flipped crossing an edge.


These pictures illustrate that a GeometryNodes modifier, detailed thereafter, can tag edges at the border of flipped parts or at the border of UV islands, across which the UV mapping is discontinuous.
The top picture shows in yellow the edges detected along such borders for the outer ring.
The bottom picture is an intermediate result showing the variations of U and V along these edges in the Spreadsheet Editor. It is to notice that variations are null in U direction, which is the flipped coordinate in this demonstration case. It is foreseen that such variations could be analysed to assess the flipped coordinate in general.
GeometryNodes graph

(An Edge Corners node mimicking the Edge Vertices node is developed to recover the corners on both side of an edge, assuming no more than two faces are connected to a single edge. Then the UVs at those corners are compared.)

Preliminary diagnostic


(No correction is proposed for the time being, only a visualisation of flipped faces (in red) and edges with discontinuous UV maps (in yellow). This will be used to determine UV islands later...)
Resources
Blender file with packed texture images: 

I am terribly sorry I am running out of time tonight for a more detailed explanation (instead of bits of sentences !). I will improve this asap. Could you at least let us know if this is in the direction (at least for the diagnostic) you are looking for ?

I'm just going to say you're definitely on a very similar path to what I've been. And the visuals of flipped UVs certainly appears correct. Unfortunately I've yet to find a functional equation that will identify the direction(s) of the flip. I do want to thank you for actually looking into my problem, and wish you good luck!

Your math problem does not make much sense. It is like looking at a coin and wonder is there an equation that can answer which side the coin was facing when it was laying in a hand. The answer is: it does not matter.

Are you sure the problem is even with the UVs and not your normal map? The mesh looks messed up with the normal in your blend file, however when I download the image you posted and apply that it looks completely fine. I'm not familiar with the .dds format but it's not anything I've ever seen in used for a normal map.
This is how it looks once I use the image just saved as a .PNG from the browser.

Node tree, inverted the G channel, making sure the texture is set to Non-Color.


See, that's part of the problem. If you set the normal map color space as you should, to non-color, Blender will happily run with it - regardless of any flipped UVs. Unfortunately the target game engine is a lot pickier. In order to get Blender to have a similar result, you have to set the color space to sRGB, then you'll get a similar result. Like I said, you can definitely verify that there are a lot of flipped UVs by selecting said UVs with Magic UV

Your original map doesn't work with the same settings. I would check your normal map first before jacking with winding order and recalculating individual face tangents. That makes no sense whatsoever.

you've literally made an answer proving there's nothing wrong with the normal map.

It's not the normal map you're using. It's one I downloaded from this website. It's a png file. Yours is some .dds. Regardless your first thought for fixing this issue should not be manually recalculate the tangent base for each face. There is about 5 other ways to fix this issue I guarantee it that are simpler and more straightforward than that.

It's the same image - the one I posted on this site is merely the .dds converted to .png in order to appear on the site. But minus any image data lost due to imgur's resampling, it's the same image. I assure you, it's not my first thought. I've been struggling and investigating this issue for over a month. At first I thought it might be that the normal map wasn't tangent space. And after trying to find a way to covert an object space or world space normal to tangent space, I discovered the flipped UVs. Upon experimentation, I discovered that unflipping said UVs would fix my problem

Then the goal was to find a way to automate this fixing, due to the number of flipped UVs, and having no clear way of determining which direction they needed to be flipped. I even tried ChatGPT first, to see if maybe it could help (not really), so out of the last resort I turned to real people. And now I get to deal with everybody gaslighting me, telling me the problem that literally all the evidence is pointing to, isn't the problem. while not offering any better solutions.

So, after breaking down and doing it "manually" (flipping sections of UV islands) and being unable to avoid weird shading artifacts, I broke down and decided to completely redo the UV Unwrapping. Then, using Substance Designer I baked new textures based off the original UVs and textures.

So I was right to not understand the question then. The problem was never where described.

To be fair I was still struggling to discover the entire problem- and what was described certainly was part of the problem, it's just that it also included UVs that weren't flipped, but still  poorly oriented. I realize that "poorly oriented" isn't very descriptive, but i'm still struggling on determining what was causing the normal related issues. And seeing as how doing a fresh unwrap solved the issue, it was definitely UV related. I just wish there was a way to solve it without starting from scratch
